# Install apt-get on openSUSE

Tags: apt, opensuse, zypper

On my system, openSUSE (15.1) is installed, as is `zypper` packet manager, which I'm not used to. Specifically, I think it lacks a huge amount of software, that I would like to use. I did already manage to install `yum` and add some repositories, but there is not much more content. [This question about Enterprise Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/374223/installing-apt-get-on-redhat) seems somewhat related, but didn't help for my OS.

As I prefer having a packet manager like `apt-get` over building everything from source, I wonder if there is a way to install it here. `Yast` was not so useful either

Comment: If you want Debian why not install Debian?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not for me to decide in this company

Comment: What you want is not `apt-get`, it's Debian's repositories of software. My suggestion would be to talk to your (new) colleagues, they probably have similar needs to you, and have found ways to fulfill them on openSUSE.

Comment: [Cross-site related?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357816/install-apt-get-on-linux-red-hat-server)

Answer (score 2):

I only have a frustrating answer for you. You can of course always [build the Debian packaging system (`dpkg`/`apt`) from source](http://packages.debian.org/stable/admin/apt-src). That would be the most straight forward answer to what you're asking. But I would be doing you a huge disservice by not telling you why you shouldn't do that, so I'll do that for you as well. SUSE is built around RPMs and while I like dpkg better than RPM, I would never try to convert an RPM based distro to a debian based distro because they're architected differently. This is partly taken [from here *(archive)*](http://web.archive.org/web/20200212184026/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729673/install-apt-get-on-opensuse), where there also is more Info.

---

Just for an overview ([source in this *archived* page)](http://web.archive.org/web/20200212184026/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729673/install-apt-get-on-opensuse)):

- `apt`(-get) is a package manager for **Debian** + **Ubuntu** + **Linux Mint** and all Linux Distributions build in Debian
- **Redhat**, **fedora** and **CentOS** are using `dnf`/`yum` package manager
- **ArchLinux** and all distributions build in arch as **Manjaro**, ... use `pacman` package manager
- "Your" **openSUSE** uses `zypper` package manager, which is not so bad. You can consider searching for how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`yast2`, specifically either `yast2 sw_single` or `yast2 online_update` are the best ways to handle software installation on opensuse, if you have a gui running. These allow you to list delve into the individual repositories. And `yast2 repositories` allows you to configure the repositories, strangely enough. `yast2` is very useful, it's the best system I have ever found.

Comment: yast2 tells me `Qt GUI wanted but not found, falling back to ncurses.` (but `libqt4` is installed) and loads a 1980-style ugly interface. But I would prefer a cli-tool anyways.